# C# Locks and Multi Threading on a queue

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I am writing a multi threaded application and I have concerns with 2 threads access a queue

Thread 1 puts items in a queue for processing
Thread 2 removes items from the queue to process

Thread 1 runs once a minute due to the nature of the data it is pulling.
Thread 2 is always running, it removes an item from the queue and sleeps for 100ms.  I have to do this to ensure that I don't overwhelm a service it calls when it dequeues an item.

I assume both threads should place a lock on the queue when adding or removing items from it.  Are there any further considerations?  For instance say Thread 1 has a lock and Thread 2 tries to access it.  Does Thread 2 simply know to wait and resume once the lock is removed?

Would it be preferable to use a ConcurrentQueue and just TryDequeue and if it fails just go about its 100 ms sleep?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's even easier if you use a `BlockingCollection<T>` like I do in NuGet's VS console dispatcher for my PostKey/WaitKey implementation. The consuming thread calls `Take(...)` which will block until another thread calls `Add(...)`. There is no need to poll. Additionally, you may wish to pass a cancellation token to the `Take` method so another thread can stop the consumer thread if it's currently waiting for an `Add` that will never come. Here are the relevant methods:

```
private readonly BlockingCollection<VsKeyInfo> _keyBuffer = 
      new BlockingCollection<VsKeyInfo>();
private CancellationTokenSource _cancelWaitKeySource;

// place a key into buffer
public void PostKey(VsKeyInfo key)
{
    if (key == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
    }
    _keyBuffer.Add(key);
}

// signal thread waiting on a key to exit Take
public void CancelWaitKey()
{
    if (_isExecutingReadKey && !_cancelWaitKeySource.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _cancelWaitKeySource.Cancel();
    }
}

// wait for a key to be placed on buffer
public VsKeyInfo WaitKey()
{
    try
    {
        // raise the StartWaitingKey event on main thread
        RaiseEventSafe(StartWaitingKey);

        // set/reset the cancellation token
        _cancelWaitKeySource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _isExecutingReadKey = true;

        // blocking call
        VsKeyInfo key = _keyBuffer.Take(_cancelWaitKeySource.Token);

        return key;
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        _isExecutingReadKey = false;
    }
}
```

See http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/45e353aca7f4#src%2fVsConsole%2fConsole%2fConsole%2fConsoleDispatcher.cs for more details.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine IMO.

Comment: Why?  The OP has stated that he/she is going to wait 100ms anyway to prevent overloading some downstream service, so using a blocking queue here is redundant.  It's just a waste of kernel calls and CPU cycles.  swannee's ConcurrentQueue + sleep() loop is fine.

Comment: @MartinJames I'm not following. You're telling me that constantly polling on a sleep/spin is less of a "waste of kernel calls and CPU cycles" than signalling? Additionally, the 100ms sleep can be performed after a successful Take to effect the desired throttling.

Comment: Polling is a wasteful design in the first place, anyway to move away from it is good IMO.

Comment: OK, I get it.  +1 for blocking queue. It will reduce the ~50ms latency under those conditions where the input arrives at intervals much greater than 100ms.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are locking on the same "sync" object, thread 2 will wait for thread 1 and vice-versa.  I think the ConcurrentQueue is a good idea because it's already specified as thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

`ConcurrentQueue` is thread safe so you wouldn't need to lock, just call `TryDequeue` and you will be fine with no other special coding.  Do not iterate it though, per the documentation, it will snapshot on iteration (unless that was what you wanted): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287144.aspx

> The enumeration represents a moment-in-time snapshot of the contents of the queue. It does not reflect any updates to the collection after **GetEnumerator** was called. The enumerator is safe to use concurrently with reads from and writes to the queue.

Honestly I think you would be better off just having Thread 1 spawn a thread (or `Task`) whenever it needs something done and using some sort of throttling synchronization (like an [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx))

Comment: 'Honestly I think you would be better off just having Thread 1 spawn a thread (or Task) whenever it needs something done' - doesn't sound like a good plan to me - it's much more complex than a sleep() loop and risks runaway threads.  One loopy thread is much easier and safer.  That said, the interaction with the service-that-gets-overloaded may possibly be done in a more efficient way, but we don't have enough info. on that.

Comment: The entire purpose of the TPL is for spawing async tasks, so not sure how its much more complex or risks runaway threads.

Comment: I should add: any moreso than any multi-threaded programming in .NET, its all potentially dangerous...

Comment: TPL tasks, OK:)  Continually spawning threads, not so good :(   I agree that .NET thread support could do with some work, but poor thread support is not .NET specific, (other languages/environments are worse).

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to sleep for 100ms anyway, you can pretty much implement the queue any way you want as long as it's thread-safe.  A simple queue with a lock/mutex, a ConcurrentQueue, they're all fine.

'For instance say Thread 1 has a lock and Thread 2 tries to access it. Does Thread 2 simply know to wait and resume once the lock is removed' - Thread 2 waits until the lock is released, yes.